# Similarity of two rows placed into new column, based on column condition

Tags: python, calculated-columns, cosine-similarity

I am struggling to result the similarity between a series of two rows into a new series of columns if and only if another column meets a specific criteria. For example, suppose I have a df with four people, their friend status, and their social preferences.

```
preference = {'person': ["Sara","Jordan","Amish","Kimmie"],'game_night':[30,10,50,30], 'movies': [10,10,20,10], 'dinner_out': [20,20,30,10] }
near = {'person': ["Sara","Jordan","Amish","Kimmie"], 'friendSara':[0,1,0,0], 'friendJordan': [1,0,1,1], 'friendAmish': [0,1,0,1], 'friendKimmie': [0,1,1,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=preference)
near_df = pd.DataFrame(data=near)
```

Please challenge me if you feel there is a better way to organize the df or to approach the problem, but I'm looking to, in this example, create a series of new columns named 'simSara', 'simJordan', etc. that fill with the `dot(person1_preferences, person2_preferences)/(norm(person1_preferences)*norm(person2_preferences))` between each person's 3 social preferences and the others. For example, the first column added named 'simSara' would have a second row populated by 0.873 (because Jordan and Sara are friends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a numpy array that summarizes each person's preferences as a vector, with each vector being a `np.array` as well

```
prefVec = df.apply(lambda x: np.array([x.game_night,x.movies,x.dinner_out]),axis=1).to_numpy()
```

Should have something like this:

```
array([
    array([30, 10, 20]), 
    array([10, 10, 20]), 
    array([50, 20, 30]),
    array([30, 10, 10])
], 
dtype=object)
```

define a custom function for your operation:

```
def getVal(v1,v2):
    return np.sum(v1*v2)/(np.sqrt((v1**2).sum())*np.sqrt((v2**2).sum()))
```

Now we essentially need to do a custom inner product using our previously defined function. `np.frompyfunc` takes our custom function and integers specifying number of inputs and outputs of our custom function. By passing `prefVec` vertically and horizontally to this `customFunc`, we broadcast the operation. This means our horizontal `prefVec` is "stretched" into a matrix, which we will then have it go through our custom inner product with our column `prefVec`:

```
customFunc = np.frompyfunc(getVal,2,1)
out = customFunc(prefVec.reshape(-1,1),prefVec)
#                  ^column prefVec       ^horizontal prefVec
```

`out` should look like this:

```
array([[1.        , 0.87287156, 0.99717646, 0.96698756],
       [0.87287156, 1.        , 0.86094603, 0.73854895],
       [0.99717646, 0.86094603, 1.        , 0.97823198],
       [0.96698756, 0.73854895, 0.97823198, 1.        ]])
```

Turning it into a dataframe by getting a list of persons from your original `df.person` column

```
pd.DataFrame(
    out,
    columns=df.person.apply(lambda x: 'sim{}'.format(x)).to_numpy(),
    index=df.person
).reset_index()
```

output:

```
    person  simSara simJordan   simAmish    simKimmie
0   Sara    1.000000    0.872872    0.997176    0.966988
1   Jordan  0.872872    1.000000    0.860946    0.738549
2   Amish   0.997176    0.860946    1.000000    0.978232
3   Kimmie  0.966988    0.738549    0.978232    1.000000
```

If you want them all in the same dataframe, merge the above output with your original df on the `person` column

Comment: thanks, jeff, really appreciate it. will have to spend some time digesting.

Comment: Sorry for the bunch of edits, did it in a rush during work and remembered stuff that I should've done better later

Comment: all the more impressed and grateful 